# Posicionar barra de inserção em div editavel jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando a API summernote como editor para e-mail, ela cria uma div para ser usada como textarea. A unica referencia que deixa é a classe "note-editable".
Eu fiz um codigo para substituição de uma palavra por uma tag com content-editable false para que ao usuario tentar apagar, apagar todo o texto dela. o codigo que utilizo:

```
function insertTag(string, tag){
    string[0] = string[0]  + '<span contentEditable="false" class="enfatizar">' + tag + '</span>&nbsp;';
    var position = string[0].lenght;
    code = string[0] + string[1];
    $('#inputMsgEmail').code(code);
}
```

Queria através da lenght retornada inserir a barra de inserção na div '.note-editable', algo como:

```
$('.note-editable').caretPosition(position);
```

Comment: Essa função `code` é do plugin (summernote)?

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando [este summernote](http://summernote.org/), certo? Se sim, vamos lá.

A API oferece um callback de `onChange`, que, um dos parâmetros enviados é o 'content', acho que seria valido utilizar tal callback para verificar o conteúdo e então adicionar as classes e tratativas.

Quanto a sua dúvida, não entendi muito bem, poderia ser mais claro? :)

Mas, vendo seu código, reparei que você não está usando a variável `position` em nenhum lugar da sua função, e, por tal ser local a mesma acaba sendo inutilizada ao longo do seu arquivo.

Comment: Sim, esse mesmo. Bem, eu tenho que inserir uma tag similar a do facebook, twitter, que se substitua sozinha por um elemento não editavel e em destaque, ao usuario digitar @ aluno, surgir a tag _<span> contentEditable="false" class="enfatizar">@ ALUNO</span>_, para ao tentar apagar um caractere apagar a frase toda, o que preciso é reposicionamento da barra de inserção apos a troca da palavra @ aluno para tag, a variavel position seria para o reposicionamento da barra de inserçao apos a palavra substituida, ou se possivel, capturar a posição por um metodo e depois restaurar...